# Preciso inserir datas em uma tabela temporária em ordem crescente

Tags: sql, postgresql

Boa tarde amigos!

Preciso incluir datas em uma tabela temporária em colunas alternadas, separadas por posições: exemplo:

Dados que tenho agora:

**TABELA DE ENTRADA**

```
+=======+================+============+===============+============+===============+===========+
| ID    |  DATA01        |  STATUS01  |  DATA02       |  STATUS02  |  DATA03       |  STATUS03 |
+=======+================+============+===============+============+===============+===========+
| ID01  |  '10/12/2022'  |  0         |  '15/10/2022' |  1         |  '16/07/2021' |  2        |
+-------+----------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

*Preciso incluir na temporária da seguinte maneira:*

**TABELA TEMPORÁRIA**

```
+=======+=================+===================+=================+===================+=================+===================+==+
| ID    |  DATA_POSIÇÃO1  |  STATUS_POSIÇÃO1  |  DATA_POSIÇÃO2  |  STATUS_POSIÇÃO2  |  DATA_POSIÇÃO3  |  STATUS_POSIÇÃO3  |  |
+=======+=================+===================+=================+===================+=================+===================+==+
| ID01  |  '16/07/2021'   |  2                |  '15/10/2022'   |  1                |  '10/12/2022'   |  0                |  |
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--+
```

OBS: Vale ressaltar que nos dados de origem podem existir colunas com valores nulos.

Não estou conseguindo pensar em uma lógica para que eu consiga popular esses dados na temporária, alguém consegue me auxiliar?

Comment: Qual seria o problema ? Inverter o pivot ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Opa, olá! Jonathan.
Nesse formato de armazenamento eu acho difícil. Recomendo fortemente que você modifique o formato.
Ao invés de colocar as datas em colunas separadas, você concentra todas na mesma coluna, e adiciona um identificador para elas, o que aparentemente já esta sendo feito pelo campo "status_posição". Assim, você sempre vai conseguir usar sempre um order by, ou algo nesse sentido, pra inserir ou visualizar a informação que precisar.

Da uma olhada no exemplo da imagem de como ficaria.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DykaP.png